# Cluster Load Balance Problems using CentOS / Varnish

Tags: nginx, centos, load-balancing

I have 3 VPS servers named as varnish(which runs centos 7 and varnish)

The other two servers have wordpress installed and are called nginx01 and nginx02.

On both servers I have created the I have created the /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf and got some basic stuff in their for the domain name....

When I go to vanish machine ip I can see the default nginx file on nginx01 and nginx02. So I know that its setup correctly but what I cant seem to figure out is how to make the vanish ip actually display the nginx01 and nginx02 content and how I actually get the vanish ip to work with my domain name as this has no web server attached to it as its just a load balancer.

Wondering where I have missed a step?

Comment: What is Vanish? Do you mean Varnish for caching?

Comment: Got it working in the end :)